General formulation of an optimal control problem
I am reading a paper on optimal control and the way they define the problem questionned me on the interest of such formulation.
We consider $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$, $x(t)\in Y\subset\mathbb{R}^{m}$ for $t\in\Omega$, $u(t)\in Z\subset\mathbb{R}^k$ and we specify, on the boundary, the control to be $u_{\partial} : \partial\Omega\to U_{\partial}$. Then the problem is
$$
\inf_{x , u, u_{\partial}}\{\int_{\Omega}L(t,x(t),Dx(t), u(t))dt + \int_{\partial\Omega}L(t,x(t),Dx(t), u(t))d\sigma(t)\}
$$
with constraint given by
$$
F(t,x(t),Dx(t),u(t)) = 0, F_{\partial}(t,x(t),u(t)) = 0
$$
Where $F$ and $F_{\partial}$, as $u$ and $u_{\partial}$, differs on $\Omega$ and $\partial\Omega$.
The functions are all considered measurable and they assume to work with weak derivative (so on Sobolev spaces).
Since this kind of generalized formulation is new for me I tried to come back on the formulation I am familiar with (Bolza formulation), namely with $x$ differentiable and assuming that my dynamic $f$ and my control $u$ satisfy the hypothesis necessary to apply Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem to be less regarding on this.
Here is my attempt and the question raised by this attempt :
First we put
$$
F(t,x(t),Dx(t),u(t)) = f(t,x(t),u(t)) - Dx(t)
$$
Then, the integration on $\partial\Omega$ becomes the evaluation with respect to the Dirac measures on ${t_0}$ and ${t_1}$, putting $L_{\partial}(t) = G(x(t))$ and letting $G(x(t_0))=0$ we recover the usual Bolza formulation.
However, I do not see the interest of putting conditions on the boundary for $u$ and $F$, and in fact in my process to recover the usual Bolza formulation, I do not use them. I am wondering where I am wrong.
If you have any idea or hints to give do not hesitate please.
Thank you a lot !
